# How can I update a Git clone that mirrors a CVS repo?

Tags: git, cvs, clone, mirror

I need to make some changes to Eclipse BIRT. So I cloned the Git repository `git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.birt/org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.git`

But this clone doesn't contain the CVS tag `BIRT_2_6_2_Release_201102151647`

What is an efficient way to import all the missing CVS revisions into my clone of the Git repo at `dev.eclipse.org`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember the only tool that supports repeated, incremental synching of git to cvs (and a lot of other VCSes) is **[Tailor](http://progetti.arstecnica.it/tailor/)**